# Storing SMTP outside the Web.Config File

Tags: asp.net, smtp, web-config

For some time now I've been storing my connection and app settings in an external file and just referencing that file via my web.config. This works really well because it allows me to keep separate connection strings and app settings. This is really handy since I find during development I will often make many changes to the webconfig and I hate having to manage the environment specific values every time I need to update my web.config.

Is there anyway I can achieve this with he SMTP configuration sections in the web.config.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Sure, you can use the configSource attribute.

Example:

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
   <smtp configSource="MailSettings.config"/>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Then put your mailSettings configuration data in MailSettings.config

So then your MailSettings.config file would have something like:

```
    <network 
    host="relayServerHostname" 
    port="portNumber"
    userName="username"
    password="password" />
```

**Update**: looks like it may need to actually go in the smtp node to work properly, so I've updated the above code to indicate that - same idea, only this one should work. :)

Comment: Cool! I didn't know you could do that!

Comment: This is one of those ASP.NET features I wish I knew earlier!

Comment: Ahhh I was trying this previously I was just forgeting to put it inside the system.net node... whooops.. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Yeah, wierd how you can't confisource the mailsettings element. One comment though - I would use smtp.config rather than mainsettings.config now, to avoid confusion (you are breaking out the smtp node, not the mainsettings node).

Comment: MailSettings.config file needs to also wrap the <network .../> node with <smtp>.

Comment: Note that your `smtp.config` file needs to use `<smtp>` as the root element without being under `<mailSettings>` or `<system.net>` (your main .config file already nests it as such) otherwise trying to use with the `MailSettingsSectionGroup` class will throw errors. If IntelliSense says "the 'smtp' element is not declared" you're doing it right...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what I have here is only for newer versions of .NET. I got a runtime error using the accepted answer.

Please update the accepted answer with the code block below if working with newer versions of .NET. The smtp node should also be in the separate file - not just the network node. The whole smtp node in the actual Web.config file is replaced by the file you put there - unlike in the appSettings where it seems to add to it.

Web.config -

```
  <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
          <smtp configSource="your-source-file">
          </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
```

Your file -

```
   <smtp from="noreply@example.com">
      <network
        host="your-host"
        port="your-port"
        userName="your-user-name"
        password="your-password"/>
    </smtp>
```

Answer (score -2):

My software stores it in the registry, even in production.

Comment: Why would a web app store this in the registry?

Comment: Because we have other remoting methods besides web.

Comment: i would recommend not using the registry

Comment: Holy cow. How is storing it in the registry and configured by a pre-provided program so that we can expect non-tech users to actually do it less secure for an application that needs full trust anyway?