# Multiple ASP.NET Configuration Files

Tags: asp.net, deployment, web-config

I have found a number of pieces of information on having multiple ASP.NET configuration files for a web deployment.  However, I am still unsure if I can accomplish what I want to accomplish.

Basically, the website I am working on can be deployed to three different sites.  Depending on the site that it is deployed to, the configuration settings need to be changed.  What I would like to do is have configuration files for each possible configuration (full web.config files) and then be able to tell a deployment build which config file to use for a particular deployment (I can edit this manually if necessary).

Is there something as simple as pointing to a different .config file, or do I need to do something more sophisticated?

**EDIT:** One particular concern that I have is that I also need settings in system.net for mail settings, etc.  So, I'm not looking to *only* override the appSettings.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any configuration section - such as `<smtp>` - can be "externalized", e.g. stored in an external file.

Other than the `file=` statement on `<appSettings>` (which is available only for app settings :-() it's not a "additional" setting - you just point your config system to an external file.

So you could have this in your app.config/web.config:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp configSource="smtp.test.config" />
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

and this in your `smtp.test.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<smtp>
  <network host="smtp.test.com" port="244" userName="test" password="secret" />
  <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\temp\mails"/>
</smtp>
```

This works as of .NET 2.0 (maybe even 1.x), and it works for every configuration **section** - but not for configuration **section groups** like `<system.web>`.

Of course, you can now create additional config files, like `smtp.staging.config` and so forth, and now your problem has been reduced to replacing a single line in your web.config.

You can do this using an installation script, a XML preprocessor, or even by human intervention.

It doesn't completely solve the problem as [.NET 4 and the web.config transformations](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx) hopefully will, but it's a step and a bit of help.

Comment: Okay.  I thought this might be the solution (thank you for verifying it).  I was hope I could just have two, full-fledged, configuration files and I could just tell a build or something which one to use.

Comment: well, you can always define post-build steps, either in Visual Studio or a MSBuild environment, which would copy the appropriate config files to your output directory

Comment: @marc_s - One (minor) problem I'm running into.  I get a warning that "The 'smtp' element is not declared." and it's happening on the external files.  Any thoughts or suggestions as to why this is happening?

Comment: @Jason: that's just the Visual Studio intellisense that's not 100% up to snuff. VS doesn't fully know how to deal with these "partial" config files. But it works - sure does!

Comment: @marc_s - Yup.  :-)  I saw it worked.  I just don't like having warnings it my project.  Ah well, guess there's not much I can do about that.  Thanks again for your help, though!

Answer (score 1):

On your main `web.config` add the following attribute to `appSettings`

```
<appSettings file="Web.site1.config">
```

Then, asp.net will see both files as one. You can edit `web.config` in order to *include* a different external file, depending on the Site.

Comment: Okay, this is what I started with.  However, I also need other settings such as the SMTP settings in system.net.  Does this solution that that into account?  (I updated my question to reflect this.)

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804427/storing-smtp-outside-the-web-config-file

Comment: this **only** works for <appSettings>, unfortunately. No other config sections support this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in .Net Framework 4. ScottGu shows a quick demo of it in his [recent talk in Sweden](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/02/asp-net-4-asp-net-mvc-and-silverlight-4-videos-of-my-talks-in-europe.aspx). In his example he has staging, production etc. with each file having (potentially) different content.

Comment: Good to hear this.  However, I'm still on .NET 2 and won't be upgrading in the foreseeable future.