# how can I read the files copied to the output directory in ASP .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, reflection

I have a VS 2012 Web service project that includes a file called myconfig.xml, I've set the copy action properties to this file to "copy always"

I try to load the XML files with this line:

```
doc.Load("myconfig.XML");
```

However ASP.net raises an exception because it cannot read the file from C:\program files (x86)\IIS Express 7

I've tried this:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

But it returns the path to a temp directory, how can I get the actual location of myconfig.XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP.NET you should always use `Server.MapPath`

```
// root folder
var docPath = Server.MapPath("/doc.xml");

// some other folder
var docPath = Server.MapPath("/folder/doc.xml");
```

Comment: that's it, Server.MapPath works :) is there some method that returns the same value and I can use for both desktop and web apps?

Comment: Does `Server.MapPath()`  work in all environments?  Web, console, service worker, containers?

Comment: I am using asp.net core and it cannot find any reference to "Server"

Comment: @Zapnologica question is about asp.net, asp.net core has different architecture, as static files are injected into services and you have to store reference to static files folder globally somewhere in the app.

Answer (score 3):

Should be

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

In web environments, you can use `AppDomain` to figure out the directories, e.g.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that asp.net allows you to create multiple config files ?

Look at the accepted answer for this post, it should point you in the right direction,

[Multiple ASP.NET Configuration Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065889/multiple-asp-net-configuration-files)